# Return the LastWriteTime of a specified registry key on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Using Powershell, how can I enumerate the LastWriteTime of a specified registry key on a remote machine?

The remote machine does not have Powershell installed so Powershell remoting is out. .NET and WMI are available. I have successfully used the RegEnumKeyEx function in the Advapi32.dll to get the lpftLastWriteTime on a local machine.

Comment: I can't seem to find any alternative to Advapi32.dll except regedt32.exe, which I don't think works remotely itself.  :(

Comment: I poked around and nothing obvious came to mind. [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey() is what I have used in the past for remote registry access, but I don't think it exposes the write times

Comment: Thanks Jason and EB. We are still looking as well. I'll keep you posted if we find something.

Answer (score 2):

How about using LogParser, available from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659)?

And here's a code example employing the COM object:

```
$query = @"

    SELECT 
        Path, 
        KeyName, 
        ValueName, 
        Value, 
        LastWriteTime 
    INTO $outfile 
    FROM \\remotecomputername\HKLM\etc\etc
    WHERE LastWriteTime BETWEEN 
        TIMESTAMP('2011/08/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss') AND 
        TIMESTAMP('2011/09/06 00:00:00', 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss') 
    ORDER BY LastWriteTime DESC

"@

$inputtype = New-Object -comObject MSUtil.LogQuery.RegistryInputFormat
$outputtype = New-Object -comObject MSUtil.LogQuery.CSVOutputFormat
$outfile = 'c:\temp\outfile.csv'
$logObject = new-object -com MSUtil.LogQuery
$result = $logObject.ExecuteBatch($query, $inputtype, $outputtype) | Out-Null
```

You could provide multiple comma-separated values in the FROM clause to query more than one computer if required. Further reading [here](http://muegge.com/blog/?p=65).

Comment: this no longer w orks :(